# Algorithm for laying out grids (html-like tables) with row/column spans

Tags: algorithm, layout, linear-algebra, linear-programming

This problem should have the same solution for the horizontal as well as for the vertical, so I'll only present the horizontal case. Consider the following layout with 3 columns, 3 rows and 2 column spans (merged cells):

```
|--A--|---B--|----C----|
|--D--|-------E--------|
|------F-----|----G----|
```

Each column (A, B, C) has a preferred width. In addition, each segment (A, B, C, D, E, F, G) has a minimum width. The requirement is to compute the width of each segment such that any overflow over the preferred width (caused by the minimum width constraint) gets distributed evenly over the free space (underflow) in the other segments, as much as possible before enlarging the segments to accommodate the minimum width constraint.

Comment: Can each row be treated as independent?

Comment: Related: The TeX layout algorithm ([link](https://github.com/bramstein/typeset), [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109764/texs-algorithms-for-breaking-paragraph-into-lines-and-setting-the-glue)).

Comment: No, it's a grid. They have to align.